# gxt GridInlineEditing doesn't notify data change in ListStore when the user completeEdit

Tags: gwt, gxt

Actually I am using GWT with gxt (3.1) framework. I want to create an editable grid.

So I write the code :

```
List<ColumnConfig<String[], ?>> l = createColumnList(cols);

gridDataDisplay = new Grid<String[]>(store, new ColumnModel<String[]>(l));

int indice = 0;
final GridEditing<String[]> editing = new GridInlineEditing<String[]>(gridDataDisplay);
for(ColumnConfig<String[], ?> columnConfig : l) {
    if (!notEditable.contains(indice)) {
        ColumnConfig<String[], String> tempColumnConfig = (ColumnConfig<String[], String>) columnConfig;
        editing.addEditor(tempColumnConfig, new TextField());
     }
     indice++;

 }
```

So I follow the tutorial [Grid Editing](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/widgets/grid/edit/GridEditing.html). 
With the code below, I can modify my data by click on the column cell. But when validate : the change don't appear on my table. The Grid dislay the old value until call store.commitChanges();

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out what is the problem. I guess it will help other people.

When, I created my ListStore, I use a keyProvider an integer that I increment every time I add a new record.

Apparently, the key keyProvider must use only the model attribute.